# Split screen into 4 re-size able section without plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to split my screen into 4 sections so, i can easily re-size it by mouse drag event,
As this question was arises many times but no body given the perfect solution for the same,So help me to finding the solution,

Asked in : [ExtJS 4: Make Portal Columns Splitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495390/extjs-4-make-portal-columns-splitting),[Three Sections To Resize With Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348871/three-sections-to-resize-with-browser)

I wanna do something like [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) .As they divide screen in four draggable section .

[Click to view Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNdgN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## I solved the above problem and here is a link for that :

This is *Plugin free* to *split screens* into many sections, here i code for 4 sections like jsfiddle.

I use the

```
Resize();
```

to resize my all DIv elements.

Check link below for Splitted Screens :

[Click for solution](http://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/4HNZ7/1/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin doing exactly this called [jQuery UI Layout](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/). **([Demo](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/simple.html))**

Also an older one called [Splitter](http://www.methvin.com/splitter/). **([Demo](http://www.methvin.com/splitter/4psplitter.html))**

Comment: Thanks for reply ,but i don't want to use any plugin, please provide me any trick or code to implement this. @Magnus Engdal

Comment: In that case you need to narrow down your question and provide any code you have tried so far. There is no *simple trick* I'm afraid. If you show us your code we could help you with more specific problems.

Comment: i am working on that.. after completion ,i also put my answer on my own post..this is possible without plugin.. :) @Magnus Engdal

Comment: [Click to see full Working Code](http://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/rmyK2/)
,
Please correct me if i am wrong or help me to correct the code if it is not good ? @Magnus Engdal

Comment: Very nice. I see no problems with your code, but if you intend to post it as an answer to your own question, you should make 4 sections since that is what you where asking for.

Comment: Thanks ,i'll working on the same .. :) @Magnus Engdal

Comment: Hi, I submit my answer with full solution of the problem..check it out.. and give me the feedback..? @Magnus Engdal